# Brace-or-equal-initializers default value in child doesn't seem work

Tags: c++, inheritance

I try understand what's going on here, why `bar` doesn't have default value for `name` property

```
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    std::string name = "foo default value";
    std::size_t number = 23;
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{  
    std::string name = "here i want other value";
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    std::cout<<"name="<< foo.name << " number=" << foo.number << std::endl;
    Foo * bar = &Bar();
    std::cout<<"name="<< bar->name << " number=" << bar->number << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
name=foo default value number=23
name= number=23 // why name is empty string?
```

I assume that's default generated constructos are involed in final result. But can't get it right in my mind. Can someone explain what sorcery compiler does here?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  `Foo * bar = &Bar();` should not even compile.

Comment: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.21.27702.2 for x64

Comment: @SonnyD Try compiling with `/permissive-`, as `&Bar()` is not valid, should not compile. If it compiles, it's almost always undefined behaviour.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I've tested that and unfortunately MSVS is okay with it.  Just more MSVS thinking the standard is just a guideline :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's wrong with the code?

You're invoking Undefined Behavior here:

```
Foo* bar = &Bar();
```

This code **actually shouldn't compile**, but at least two compilers accept it (the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, and the Intel C++ compiler).

This executes the following steps:

- Create a temporary instance of Bar
- Take the address of that instance
- Assign the address to the variable `bar`
- Destroy that instance

When, on the next line, you try to use `bar`, the temporary instance has already been destroyed. This invokes the undefined behavior.

#### How do we fix the Undefined Behavior?

What you're missing is a `new`:

```
// Old way; prone to memory leaks
Foo* bar = new Bar();
```

Even better, use a `unique_ptr`:

```
// New way; bar acts like a pointer, and it gets automatically deleted
// at the end of the scope
std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar = std::make_unique<Bar>();
```

This will allow you to use `bar` safely:

```
std::cout << "name=" << bar->name << " number = " << bar->number << '\n';
```

#### Why is it printing `"foo default value"` instead of `"here I want other value"`?

Variables aren't virtual. That means that if you use `bar->name`, because `bar` is a pointer to `Foo`, this refers to `name` as it's defined in `Foo`.

In order to fix this, we need to use virtual member functions:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual std::string getName() {
        return "I am foo.";
    }
    // We need to have this, so that the destructor is called correctly.
    virtual ~Foo() = default; 
};

struct Bar {
    std::string getName() override {
        return "I am actually bar.";
    }
};
```

Now, things work as intended:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar = std::make_unique<Bar>()
std::cout << bar->getName() << '\n'; //Prints "I am actually bar."
```

When, on the next line, you try to use `bar`, the temporary instance has already been destroyed. This invokes the undefined behavior.

Instead you should do:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar (new Bar());
```

Comment: *"invoking Undefined Behavior"* It shouldn't compile to begin with, so it's not UB.

Comment: Most compilers correctly recognize that the code takes the address of a temporary, and they don't compile it, but (unfortunately) both the Intel C++ compiler and the MSVC compiler accept the code.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the simpler way of having `Bar`'s constructor pass a value for `name` an appropriate constructor in `Foo`, while eliminating the `name` in `Bar`.

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez yesterday I don't have time for thanks. Thank you so much for such good explanation. I'm rookie to c++, and have backgrounds in web languages (its shame to admit it :D :) ). That's why I do this stupid things in c++.

Comment: I hope I was able to help! If you want to write more generic code, you should also take a look at using templates. They're a lot more powerful than generics are in other languages (for example, in java you can't do `T x = new T();`, but that's trivial in C++ as `T x = T();` or as `T* x = new T();`). Templates are useful because they're faster than using virtual function calls and inheritance, and you don't have to specify an interface when writing a template